# How to register decorator to be able to resolve decoree

Tags: c#, autofac, autofac-configuration

I'm using Autofac.
I'm trying to register 2 classes with same interface using decorator pattern.

```
public interface IDoable
{
    string Do();
}

public class Decoree : IDoable
{
    public string Do()
    {
        return "decoree";
    }
}

public class Decorator : IDoable
{
    public IDoable InnerDecoree { get; set; }

    public Decorator(IDoable doable)
    {
        this.InnerDecoree = doable;
    }

    public string Do()
    {
        return InnerDecoree.Do() + "decorator";
    }
}
```

I'd like to use container for resolving *two* types for 2 different cases:

- `IDoable` where I'd expect that instance would be instance of `Decorator`
- *and* for specific `Decoree` where I really need to resolve specific `Decoree` instance.

Only way how I can achieve it is using following code:

```
[Fact]
public void Both()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Decoree>()
           .Named<IDoable>("decoree")
           .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<Decoree>() // but this is not right I'd like to register it on line above somehow...
        .AsSelf()
        .SingleInstance(); 

    builder.RegisterType<Decorator>()
           .Named<IDoable>("decorator")
           .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterDecorator<IDoable>(
            (c, inner) => c.ResolveNamed<IDoable>("decorator", TypedParameter.From(inner)), "decoree")
            .As<IDoable>();

    var container = builder.Build();

    Assert.IsType<Decoree>(container.Resolve<Decoree>());
    Assert.False(container.IsRegistered<Decorator>());
    Assert.IsType<Decorator>(container.Resolve<IDoable>());


    var decoree = container.Resolve<Decoree>();
    var decorator = container.Resolve<IDoable>();
    var doable = ((Decorator)decorator).InnerDecoree;

    Assert.Same(decoree, doable); // FALSE :(
```

}

The thing is that I'd really love the last assertion to be true :) so It's same instance.

Basically my question is: Is it possible to register type both ways using *named* and *type* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you aren't specifying a scope in your registration, you are getting a different instance of `Decoree` every time it gets resolved. I would try something like

```
builder.RegisterType<Decoree>()
       .Named<IDoable>("decoree").SingleInstance();
```

In addition, you might need to combine your 2 registrations of the `Decoree` type:

```
builder.RegisterType<Decoree>()
       .Named<IDoable>("decoree")
       .AsSelf()
       .SingleInstance();
```

Comment: You're definitelly right with the scopes, however I won't solve the issue...I've updated code sample

Comment: You're my saviour, adding .AsSelf resolved that issue (that second registration became obsolette).
Interestingly before that I've tried using .As<Decoree> but that overwritten "named" rule.
Many thanks.